# PHP array with url values to new array with combined values

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried for a long time but couldn't find a way to merge an array in to a new one.
Mostly I get lost in looping and matching.;(

I would like to recieve a php 5 method that can do the following:

**Example 1**

Lets say there is an array with url's like:

```
Array(
'a',
'a/b/c',
'a/b/c/d/e',
'a/y',
'b/z',
'b/z/q/',
)
```

Every **last** folder of the url's is the folder where a user has the right to view.

I would like to send the array to a method that returns a new array like:

```
Array[](
'a/c/e'
'a/y'
'z/q'
)
```

The method has combined some elements of the origninal array into one element.
This because there is a match in allowed ending folders.

**Example 2**

```
Array(
'projects/projectA/books'
'projects/projectA/books/cooking/book1'
'projects/projectA/walls/wall'
'projects/projectX/walls/wall'
'projects/projectZ/'
'projects/projectZ/Wood/Cheese/Bacon'
)
```

I would like to get a an array like:

```
Array[](
'books/book1'
'wall'
'wall'
'projectZ/Bacon'
)
```

Then it would be great (specialy in case of the 'wall' values) to have some references to the full path's of the original array.

Comment: can you let us know the exact format of your desired output? it's confusing right now

Comment: Output is edited.

Comment: your two inputs and there corresponding outputs don't have same logic. first  one output is not having same logic what second-one have. first-one output need to be:-`Array(
'a/c/e/y'
'z/q'
)`

Comment: 'y' isn't a subfolder from 'b', 'c' or 'e'.
'y' is a subfolder from 'a'.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like below:-

```
<?php

$array = Array(
    'projects/projectA/books',
    'projects/projectA/books/cooking/book1',
    'projects/projectA/walls/wall',
    'projects/projectX/walls/wall',
    'projects/projectZ/',
    'projects/projectZ/Wood/Cheese/Bacon'
);// original array

$final_array =array(); // new array variable

foreach($array as $key=>$arr){ // iterate over original array
   $exploded_string = end(array_filter(explode('/',$arr))); // get last-value from the url string

    foreach($array as $ar){ // iterate again the original array to compare this string withh each array element
       $new_exploded_string = end(array_filter(explode('/',$ar))); // get the new-last-values from url string again
        if($arr !== $ar && strpos($ar,$exploded_string) !==false){ // if both old and new url strings are not equal and old-last-value find into url string
            if($exploded_string == $new_exploded_string ){  // if both new-last-value and old-last-value are equal
                $final_array[] = $exploded_string;
            }else{
                $final_array[] = $exploded_string.'/'.$new_exploded_string ;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/846738

Answer (score 2):

Well, there isn't a single built-in function for this ;)

```
$items = array(
    'projects/projectA/books',
    'projects/projectA/books/cooking/book1',
    'projects/projectA/walls/wall',
    'projects/projectX/walls/wall',
    'projects/projectZ/',
    'projects/projectZ/Wood/Cheese/Bacon',

    'hold/mold/gold/sold/fold',
    'hold/mold/gold',
    'raja/maza/saza',
    'raja/maza',
    'mohit/yenky/client/project',

);
echo '$items = ' . nl2br(htmlspecialchars(print_r($items, true))); //Debug

// Sort, so the shorter basePath comes before the longer subPath
usort($items, function($a, $b) {
    if (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return strlen($a) > strlen($b) ? 1 : -1;
    }
});

$result = array();
while($basePath = array_shift($items)) { // As long as there is a next item
    $basePath = rtrim($basePath, '/'); // Right trim extra /
    foreach($items as $idx => $subPath) {
        if (strpos($subPath, $basePath . '/') === 0) {
            // $subPath begins with $basePath
            $result[] = preg_replace('#.*/#', '', $basePath) . '/' . preg_replace('#.*/#', '', rtrim($subPath, '/'));
            unset($items[$idx]); // Remove item from array, so it won't be matched again
            continue 2; // Continue with next while($basePath = array_shift($items))
        }
    }

    // No subPath found, otherwise continue would have called (skipping below code)
    $result[] = preg_replace('#.*/#', '', $basePath);
}

echo '$result = ' . nl2br(htmlspecialchars(print_r($result, true))); //Debug
```

PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ugq9-hy0i

Comment: Thanks. Almost. I've posted a reply.

Comment: @RalphDelnoy I've updated my answer to fix this (added the usort and new example-data). Note: you shouldn't use an answer as a reply (as it isn't an answer to your own question), instead edit your question to add (more) example-data

Comment: Okay willl notice. Thanks by the way, Iam still testing. Iam studing your method and is there a way to add have a second array that contains the full paths of the new array? So that in case of 'wall' I know witch wall?

Comment: For example replace `$result[] = preg_replace(..);` with something like `$result[] = array('short' => preg_replace(..), 'full' => $basePath)`,

Comment: Oh no.. Doesnt work with a new example. (edited array is in orininal post)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using nested loops (and, actually, you **should** avoid):

```
sort($array);
$carry = array_shift($array);
$result = [];
$i = 0;

$lastItem = array_reduce($array, function ($carry, $item) use (&$result, &$i) {
    $result[$i] = isset($result[$i]) 
        ? array_merge($result[$i], [basename($carry)]) 
        : [basename($carry)];

    if (strpos($item, $carry) !== 0) {
        $i += 1;
    }

    return $item;
}, $carry);

if (!empty($lastItem)) {
    $result[$i] = isset($result[$i]) 
        ? array_merge($result[$i], [basename($lastItem)]) 
        : [basename($lastItem)];
}

$result = array_map(function ($item) {
    return implode('/', $item);
}, $result);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf22e804209ada295c4af2bd240f06ff496d0c36).

We use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) here to get access to the previously processed item. Also, PHP has function [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php), that retrieves the basename. So you can use it and do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it works! Super! Is there a way to mark every new element with the full path. So that in case of 'wall' I know witch wall?

Comment: Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8004ed71312f4849a92fe3b0b9b8efb0e13083eb). I have extracted adding to results logic to the anonymous function, so you can change only it. Now the full path is specified in the parentheses after the basename.

Comment: Oh no.. Doesnt work with a new example. (edited array is in orininal post)